# Passing Data from Kendo UI Command Buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with 6 command buttons on each row, with the structure below, but calling different functions. I'm looking for a way to pass data down to the function, based on which button is pressed. Right now, I have 6 functions on the java side and 6 popups on the aspx side. I'm not even sure it can be done, but it's just a lot of duplicated code. Here's the command structure for each button:

```
command: [{
        name: "Edit",
        title: "Alert Email",
        width: "180px",
        click: onDataBound75
    }],
```

This is one of the 6 functions:

```
function onDataBound75(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#txtAlert").kendoEditor({
            resizable: {
                content: true,
                toolbar: true,
                encoded: false
            }
        });
        var window = $("#emailAlert_popup").kendoWindow({
            width: "600px",
            visible: false,
            modal: true,
            actions: [
                "Maximize",
                "Close"
            ],
        });
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        var viewModelAlert75 = kendo.observable({
            Alert75EmailSubject: dataItem.Alert75EmailSubject,
            Alert75EmailBody: dataItem.Alert75EmailBody,
            Alert75FromAddress: dataItem.Alert75FromAddress,
        });
        kendo.bind($("#emailAlert_popup"), viewModelAlert75);
        window.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    };
```

And here is one of the 6 popups for the aspx side:

```
<div id="emailAlert_popup" class="TT_PopupWindow">
        <div class="SearchParam">
            <label class="control-label" for="txtAlert75EmailSubject" style="width:200px">Email Subject</label>
            <input name="txtEmailSubject" id="txtAlert75EmailSubject" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
                data-bind="value: Alert75EmailSubject" />                    
        </div>
        <div class="SearchParam">
            <label class="control-label" for="txtAlert75EmailBody" style="width:200px">Email Body</label>
            <textarea id="txtAlert" rows="10" cols="30" style="height:440px" aria-label="editor" data-bind="value: Alert75EmailBody"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="SearchParam">
            <label class="control-label" for="txtAlert75FromAddress" style="width:200px">From Address</label>
            <input name="txtFromAddress" id="txtAlert75FromAddress" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
                data-bind="value: Alert75FromAddress"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="k-edit-buttons k-state-default">
            <button type="button" id="btnAlert75EmailUpdate" data-role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-primary k-grid-update" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" style="float:right"><span class="k-icon k-i-check"></span>Update</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnAlert75Cancel" data-role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-cancel" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="1" style="float:right"><span class="k-icon k-i-cancel"></span>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to have only 1 javascript function passing data over to the aspx side and only 1 popup on the aspx page?

Comment: All 6 functions and popups are equal? What changes on each one ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown On the DataSource, there are 6 separate `EmailAddress` `EmailSubject` and `EmailBody` depending on which button is pressed. I need to send those 3 data fields down to the function and to the popup.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undertand clearly what you mean.

Comment: On the DataSource, there are 6 `emailAddress`, 6 `emailBody` and 6 `emailSubject`. Then there are 6 buttons tied to each group of `emailAddress`, `emailBody` and `emailSubject`. So, lets say the first command button is pressed: `emailAddress1`, `emailBody1` and `emailSubject1` needs to be passed to the function only. The same thing goes for the other command buttons, but they just send different `emailAddress`, `emailBody` and `emailSubject`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, for anyone else looking for the same scenario. This is how I achieved it with 1 function and 1 kendowindow:

```
command: [{
        name: "Alert75Edit",
        title: "Alert Email",
        width: "180px",
        click: AlertEmails
    }],
```

DataSource:

```
DataSources = {
    EditorWindow:{
        EmailSubject:null,
        EmailBody:null,
        EmailFromAddress:null
    }
};
```

Single function:

```
function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var AlertType = e.data.commandName.replace("Edit", "");
    if (!$("#txtAlertEmailBody").data("kendoEditor")) {
        $("#txtAlertEmailBody").kendoEditor({
            resizable: {
                content: true,
                toolbar: true,
                encoded: false
            }
        });
    }
    var window = $("#emailAlert_popup").kendoWindow({
        width: "600px",
        visible: false,
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Maximize",
            "Close"
        ],
    });
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    EditorWindow.EmailSubject = dataItem[AlertType + "EmailSubject"];
    EditorWindow.EmailBody = dataItem[AlertType + "EmailBody"];
    EditorWindow.EmailFromAddress = dataItem[AlertType + "FromAddress"];

    var viewModelAlert = kendo.observable({
        AlertEmailSubject: EditorWindow.EmailSubject,
        AlertEmailBody: EditorWindow.EmailBody,
        AlertFromAddress: EditorWindow.EmailFromAddress,
    });
    kendo.bind($("#emailAlert_popup"), viewModelAlert);
    window.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
};
```

Single kendoWindow popup in aspx file:

```
<div id="emailAlert_popup" class="TT_PopupWindow">
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtAlertEmailSubject" style="width:200px">Email Subject</label>
        <input name="txtEmailSubject" id="txtAlertEmailSubject" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
            data-bind="value: AlertEmailSubject" />                    
    </div>
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtAlertEmailBody" style="width:200px">Email Body</label>
        <textarea id="txtAlertEmailBody" rows="10" cols="30" style="height:440px" aria-label="editor" data-bind="value: AlertEmailBody"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtAlertFromAddress" style="width:100px">From Address</label>
        <input name="txtFromAddress" id="txtAlertFromAddress" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
            data-bind="value: AlertFromAddress"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="k-edit-buttons k-state-default">
        <button type="button" id="btnAlertCancel" data-role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-cancel" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="1" style="float:right; margin:5px"><span class="k-icon k-i-cancel"></span>Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnAlertEmailUpdate" data-role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-primary k-grid-update" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" style="float:right; margin:5px"><span class="k-icon k-i-check"></span>Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```